# Tableau: Two dimensions on secondary vertical axis

Tags: tableau-api

Is it possible to have two dimensions on secondary vertical axis?

Dual Axis is allowed only on one dimension. For other it does not show the option to make it dual. Both the chart type for secondary vertical axis is Line type.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get more than two Dimensions on Secondary Vertical Axis, use "Measure Values" in row section.

This way along with primary Vertical axis, we can get multiple dimensions/attr/measures on secondary vertical axis.